# Need a dynamic size buffer when listening to a udpsocket

Tags: rust, udp, buffer

This is the current code listening to the udpsocket at port: 34254

```
use std::net::UdpSocket;
use std::str;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    {
        let socket = UdpSocket::bind("127.0.0.1:34254").expect("couldn't bind to address");
        socket.connect("127.0.0.1:34254").expect("connect function failed");
        println!("ready");
        let mut buf = [0; 2048];
        match socket.recv(&mut buf) {
            Ok(_received) =>{
                let s = match str::from_utf8(&buf) {
                    Ok(v) => v,
                    Err(e) => panic!("Invalid UTF-8 sequence: {}", e),
                };
                println!("result: {}", s);
            },
            Err(e) => println!("recv function failed: {:?}", e),
        }
    } // the socket is closed here
    Ok(())
}
```

Now, the length of my data will vary and I cannot give a size like "2048", or the buffer will run out when I send bigger data.

Can I create a dynamic size buffer (or something similar), I know that socket.send method has a length parameter, can I take advantage of that?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, what about creating a [Vector](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html)? You can create something like `Vec<u8>`, if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to confirm on the same. But as vector stores data on heap, I wanted to verify if that is the correct approach here.

Comment: Yeah, Vector was designed for such use-cases and is the only way to do what you are trying to accomplish here unless you are willing to create a custom vector implementation yourself.

Comment: `recv()` returns the actual number of bytes received. You don't need a dynamic buffer, just a buffer that is at least as large as the largest possible message you can receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, the length of my data will vary and I cannot give a size like "2048"

Do you have packed the length information of your data into the packet data? For example, the leading 4 bytes containing the length of the entire packet.

If you have such information, you could use the [UdpSocket::peek](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.peek):

> Receives single datagram on the socket from the remote address to which it is connected, without removing the message from input queue. On success, returns the number of bytes peeked.

Then you could get the length as a number, then allocate exactly the right amount of space and call.

But everything comes with a tradeoff, it needs an extra system call, which could be more expensive than getting some space from the stack.

Or, you could, just simply allocate a "big enough" array ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody stumbling upon this thread: A UDP datagram has an upper size limit which is 65,507 bytes for IPv4 and 65,527 bytes for IPv6. A sufficient sized heap allocated array (`Box<[u8; 65527]>`) can be used to to receive all package up to the max. size.

```rust
use std::net::UdpSocket;
use std::str;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    {
        let socket = UdpSocket::bind("127.0.0.1:34254").expect("couldn't bind to address");
        socket.connect("127.0.0.1:34254").expect("connect function failed");
        println!("ready");
        let mut buf: Box<[u8; 65527]> = Box::new([0; 65527]);
        match socket.recv(buf.as_mut_slice()) {
            Ok(n) =>{  // n is the number of received bytes
                let s = match str::from_utf8(&buf[..n]) {  // reading up to n
                    Ok(v) => v,
                    Err(e) => panic!("Invalid UTF-8 sequence: {}", e),
                };
                println!("result: {}", s);
            },
            Err(e) => println!("recv function failed: {:?}", e),
        }
    } // the socket is closed here
    Ok(())
}
```